# asp.net DGV Printer gridview name not find?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview

I write aspx for DGV Printer to print pdf document. I have gridview
but DGV printer says no gridview found.

```
  System.Exception: 'Null Parameter passed to DGVPrinter.'
```

[image]

My gridname is GridView1 when I wrote  `printer.PrintPreviewNoDisplay(**GridView1**);`  it's not working.

default.aspx.cs part here

```
    using System;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Windows.Forms;
        using DGVPrinterHelper;

        namespace WebApplication61
        {
            public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
            {


                protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                { }

               protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                    DGVPrinter printer = new DGVPrinter();

                    printer.Title = "DataGridView Report";

                    printer.SubTitle = "An Easy to Use DataGridView Printing Object";

                    printer.SubTitleFormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.LineLimit |

                                                  StringFormatFlags.NoClip;
                    printer.PrintSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
                    printer.PageNumbers = true;
                    printer.PageNumberInHeader = false;
                    printer.PorportionalColumns = true;
                    printer.HeaderCellAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                    printer.Footer = "Your Company Name Here";
                    printer.FooterSpacing = 15;
                    printer.PrintPreviewNoDisplay(GridView1);
                       }
                        }        
 }

 here default.aspx


    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication61.WebForm1" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .auto-style1 {
                height: 535px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class="auto-style1">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="altsurecid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="xas" HeaderText="axs" InsertVisible="True" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="xas" />
                    ...


                </asp:GridView>
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

            </div>

        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

visual studio 2017 I'm using SQL managemant, win 10